# Jsplumb change position of static anchor

Tags: static, anchor, endpoint, jsplumb

what i want to accomplish is that i can rotate jsplumb connections. You can use setAnchor to redefine an Anchor but i can't get it to work. I found this online and it works but it's not what I want.

```
jsPlumb.selectEndpoints("myclickedelement").setAnchor([ "Continuous", { faces: ["Top", "Bottom", "Left", "Right"] }])
```

I got an endpoint on the top and bottom of the object and when I rotate it i want them to be at the left and right without deleting the existing connections.

```
          jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this).parent("div").attr('id'),     { anchor:[0.5, 0, 0, -1] },
{ isSource:true,
 isTarget:true,
 paintStyle:{ lineWidth:1, strokeStyle:'#ff8700' },
 connector: 'Flowchart',
 hoverPaintStyle:{ strokeStyle:"#ff8700", lineWidth:4},
  })  
jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this).parent("div").attr('id'),   { anchor:[0.5, 1, 0, 1] },
{ isSource:true,
 isTarget:true,
 paintStyle:{ lineWidth:1, strokeStyle:'#ff8700' },
 connector: 'Flowchart',
 hoverPaintStyle:{ strokeStyle:"#ff8700", lineWidth:4},
  })
```

This is what I have to create my objects with anchors

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

```
endpoints = jsPlumb.selectEndpoints($(this).attr('id').elementId);
anchorarray = [[0.5,0,0,-1],[1,0.5,1,0],[0.5,1,0,1],[0,0.5,-1,0]];

endpoints.each(function(ep){
    if (top == 0 && ep.id.contains(clickeditem)) {
            ep.setAnchor(anchorarray[0]);
            top = 1;

        } else if (ep.id.contains(clickeditem)) {
            ep.setAnchor(anchorarray[2]);
        }
});
```